# Whenever I start vim it thinks I have pressed 'd'. How do I stop this behavior?

Tags: vim

Whenever I open vim, the first key that I press deletes things. It thinks that 'd' has been pressed, so if I type 'j' it deletes the first two lines and if I press 'G' it'll delete everything. I checked my .vimrc and by selectively commenting-out sections it appears to be this line:

```
nnoremap <C-[> gT
```

...but I don't see how that would cause it...?

Comment: It will almost certainly be your `.vimrc`; we can't help you if you don't show it.

Comment: Well, I did a little binary search commenting stuff out and found the offending line, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it: `nnoremap <C-[> gT`

Comment: To improve or clarify your question, use the "edit" link under it rather than comments. I've put the offending line into the question for you.

Comment: I can confirm that's the offending line (if I add it to my `.vimrc` I get the same behavior). Interestingly it only affects vim and not gvim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<C-[>` (or `^[`) is the same as `<Esc>`, an important key. Especially in the terminal, the sending of input keys and the control of the screen is based on it ("ANSI Escape sequences"). (This is less an issue in GVIM, which has its own implementations for that.) Therefore, **that key must not be mapped! Choose a different one.** (Also not as part of a mapping (e.g. `<Esc>x`), because that will cause delays while Vim is waiting for other keys.)

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, Vim currently cannot distinguish between `<C-[>` and `<Esc>`. Also, some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.